# How to plot two scatter-plots on the same chart?

Tags: excel, charts

I have two series that overlay pretty close in time but not exactly. So I need to plot each series with the corresponding time component to get the match. Also the number of points is different, by a factor of 10.

How to plot two scatter-plots on the same plot using the time domain as the x-axis? eg

```
t1: 0.1 0.3 0.5 ...
y1: 3   7   9   ...

t2: 0.18 0.21 0.34 0.41 0.56 ...
y2: 32   55   4    7    1    ...
```

As you can see I can't just highlight all because the series don't match up so well in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If output something like this is what you want:

[image: SO19800534 example]

then it may be simplest to plot one series (say `y1`), select the Plot Area, Select Data... and add your second (`y2`) series.

Answer (score 3):

It's also pretty easy to make the chart using the first range, then copy the X and Y values for the second series (hopefully it's in adjacent columns, but you can use Ctrl+Select to select multiple areas). Then select the chart, and use Paste Special to add the copied data as a new series, in columns, X values in first column.